# How inner class object resides in memory?

Tags: java, inner-classes

`Outer outer = new Outer();`

an `Object` of `Outer` class is created on heap and reference variable points to it.

If I understand it right when I write

`Outer.Inner inner=outer.new Inner();`

an object of `Inner` class is created on heap and `inner` points to it. In heap we have two separate objects which contains their own instance variables.

But if I write

`Outer.Inner inner=new Outer().new Inner();`

still two `Object` would be created on heap one for `Outer` and other for `Inner`. But with reference the `inner` only `Inner` `Object's` members are accessible . Who is referring to the outer `Object` on heap? If it is not referred by any reference then it should be eligible for garbage collection which would then impact the usage of `inner`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An inner class contains a hidden reference to its outer class instance. That hidden reference keeps the outer class instance alive if there are no other references to it.

To see this in action, take this source code and compile it:

```
public class Outer {
    public class Inner {
    }
}
```

Now use the java class inspection tool `javap` to see the hidden reference:

```
$ javap -p Outer\$Inner
Compiled from "Outer.java"
public class Outer$Inner {
  final Outer this$0;
  public Outer$Inner(Outer);
}
```

You'll see that there is a package-scope hidden reference called `this$0` of type `Outer` - this is the reference that I talked about above.

Answer (score 1):

Each instance of an inner class holds a reference to an instance of its outer class.  It's the reference that you get when you write `Outer.this` within one of the inner class's methods.  The anonymous `Outer` instance won't be eligible for garbage collection unless all `Inner` instances associated with it are also eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: All inner classes are non-static, otherwise it wouldn't be called an inner class (it would be called a static member class)

Answer (score 0):

Naturally, the inner holds on to strong references of the things it wants strong references to - like the other half of its instance variables which reside in Outer.